# Would it be a good practice to escape values just before adding them into db?

Tags: security, zend-framework, escaping

I have a Zend project and after time researching I've come across this idea. Of course this is security related and the purpose is to avoid xss attacks.

Other solutions would be to escape them just before showing them, but that would include a lot of special cases, and some time because Zend does not have anything like that implemented.

These are the solutions for escaping before echo-ing them in the phtml
http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/10/how-to-automatically-escape-template-variables-in-zend_view/
and https://github.com/chikaram/gnix-view

Those are a bit too old, maybe someone has already met this problem and has come with better solutions with newer features that Zend has to offer that I haven't found about.

So, would it be a good practice to escape values before adding them to db and making an exclusion array for rare special cases when I do want javascript code in my values?

If you have better solutions, links and examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: as other people told you, it's **generally** bad idea. of course in your particular case, it might work. but you should ask yourself: is your project so special that is should be done in non-standard way and are you aware of consequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it would not be, because database is for storing **data**, not "data already escaped for presentation on specific medium".

Consider eg. that you will need in the future to export it to PDF, not show it in HTML. By using your approach, this will be very hard, because the data in the database would already be broken.

Comment: Couldn't I use some unescape function for special cases for when I want to do those sort of things?

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan And what about searching?  And what about the user who is wondering why his 16 character string "must be less than or equal to 16 characters"?

Comment: Can you come up with an example where the user would have a search form and look for a string with special chars in it?

Comment: Plus can't I treat that case with unescape before comparing the two strings?

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan Imagine you have a form where users can search for companies by name.  Image there's a company named `Smith &amp; Sons`.  That could complicate searching.

Comment: Well if I escape that in the view, won't it display as Smith &amp; Sons anyway? I'm confused.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan No, because in HTML, `&amp;` is rendered as `&`.

Comment: I just realized that, was gonna delete my comment. I admit, there's a lot of cases that need to be treated. Maybe if I had my focus on just this feature for Zend, the time spent was worth it, otherwise you are right, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan: Actually it is common to do this the other way around: store raw _data_ in database, and escape it by default, but with ablity to skipe escaping. Just separate presentation from the data, you will not regret it.

Comment: Have you done it? What exactly did you do? Was it something like in the two links I posted? (those are at least two years old)

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan: Yes, I have done it in several frameworks, such as Django. In PHP one of the solutions is Twig templating language that has autoescape feature. It is a standard templating solution for Symfony2 and you can also use it in Zend: http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2011/05/using-twig-with-zend-framework/. Basically this concept of autoescaping can be used with multiple template forms - right now you can try Twig under Zend, unless someone finds Zend View counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you have all the escaped HTML and then need to use it in a JSON API?  People will wonder why their credit card statement shows up as `Smith &amp; associates`.

There's a reason escaping is done last minute.  Escaping is context sensitive.  You escape HTML only inside of HTML, in the same way that you escape strings for SQL in a different way.  By escaping last minute, you keep the actual data available for sane searching and escaping in different manners.

Besides, if you're using the MVC stuff in ZF, you should just be able to use `$this->escape()` inside of views.

Like:

```
Username: <?php echo $this->escape($this->username)); ?>
```

Comment: It would take a lot of time. That's my last resort solution. I'm trying to figure out if it's worth looking for a better way.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan I'm not sure how it would take a lot of time?

Comment: There's lots of echos in my project, also what happens if I simply miss one?

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan There's high probability than it take more time to deal with unescaping data when the time comes.  As for that, either be very careful, or adopt a naming convention for html-escaped and non-escaped strings.  Like `$hUsername = htmlentities($username);`

Comment: For whatever I decide to do, using a convention is a great idea!

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan I must admit, I stole that idea from a Joel On Software blog a while ago: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan Instead of using a lot of echos in the project, why not create your own print function that's doing echo $this->escape($msg), and use that print function instead? That way you know you aren't missing anything, as long as you haven't used a direct echo.

Answer (score 1):

**Validate input, escape output.**

You can't beat this. If you want the user to supply something that is not HTML, you **first validate** he did that (and filter out anything else). Next, you **save it in DB** (you need to **escape it for DB** usage (Zend_Db_Adapter::quote() or mysql_real_escape_string). Finally you **load it from DB** and **output it** (*with proper escaping* - Zend_View->escape()). Things differ if you echo it into JavaScript code. Than you need to escape it using javascript escape function (same goes for any other format).

Comment: If you're writing into the database, you should be using parameterized queries, not quoting, whenever possible.